# sudo sysctl -w kern.tfp.policy=1 fails?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, terminal, osx-lion

I tried to setup the kern.tfp.policy to one but it does not let me do it.

sudo sysctl -w kern.tfp.policy=1

kern.tfp.policy: 2
sysctl: kern.tfp.policy: Invalid argument

How can I set kern.tfp.policy=1.

I am doing this in order to be able to use mach_inject.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Have you tried adding your user account to `procmod` group?

Comment: I am trying to change the security policy for task_for_pid(); which is used in mach_inject.

Comment: I will hook some APIs from Quartz.

Comment: I read somewhere that adding an account to the `procmod` group is just as good (although not system-wide), would this work for you?

Comment: I tried that option.. adding account to the procmod takes time, changing the policy should be instantaneous.  I cannot ask user to wait for some time after installation of software. It should work right away. Its requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option has completely been removed from the Mac OS X kernel five years ago.

In [XNU 792](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-792.25.20/bsd/sys/sysctl.h) (Mac OS X 10.4.x Tiger), it still existed:

```
#define KERN_TFP_POLICY_DENY        0   /* Deny Mode: None allowed except privileged */
#define KERN_TFP_POLICY_PERMISSIVE  1   /* Permissive Mode: related ones allowed or privileged */
#define KERN_TFP_POLICY_RESTRICTED  2   /* Restricted Mode: privileged or setgid and realted */
```

In the more recent [XNU 1228](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1228/bsd/sys/sysctl.h) (Mac OS X 10.5.x Leopard) it's been removed:

```
#define KERN_TFP_POLICY_DENY        0   /* Deny Mode: None allowed except privileged */
#define KERN_TFP_POLICY_DEFAULT     2   /* Default  Mode: related ones allowed and upcall authentication */
```

---

Since `1` is not a valid value for this option anymore, your call fails with that error message.

It seems there's no way to circumvent this anymore, so you'll have to use the `procmod` group membership.

---

As a workaround, look into `man taskgated`. It has a parameter that allows Tiger compatibility, as well as a few others.

> Accepts the old (Tiger) convention that a process with a primary effective group of procmod or procview is allowed to get task ports. Without this option, this legacy mode is not supported.

You'd probably need to change the launchd `plist` and relaunch that service. Not sure if that's possible with your use case.